# How can I use this 'Enable Live Templates'?

Tags: intellij-idea

I wanna use like `junit template method` in Eclipse.
I was searching in `Intellij`, finally I founded this settings.
[image]

I checked that `Enable Live Templates` options.. but... nothing changed.
How Can I use that live templates?
I founded wrong? I just have to add `Live templates` directly?

Comment: How are you trying to use this Code Template?

Comment: Like `eclipse` test method. When we type `test` and enter `ctrl + space` twice, `eclipse` make code like above.

Comment: Well.. not sure that these templates in IDEA can be used like live templates (with typing and then hitting tab). But you can use it from `Generate Code` (Ctrl + N by default) | `Test Method`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it allows you to embed live templates (macros) into your file and code templates.

A contrived example would be adding a for loop to your unit test method template.  Instead of writing the for loop longhand as `for (int i; i < 10; i++) {}` you could enable live templates and write the for loop shorthand as `fori`.

See the full documentation at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html